# ADODB and SqlClient

Tags: adodb, sqlclient

Hi I am working on a migration project. The front end was developed on vb6 and back end service was build on C++ COM. Currently, we are migrating the System to .Net 4.5.

In my actual code, both the Front End and Back End Modules were using ADODB to work with he database. But in this Migration, we have decided to use SQLClient in Front End VB.Net Applciation and Back End Still use ADODB.

Can Any one tell me that is there any issues If we use ADODB and SQLCLient together in a System. Will this affect any database actions(Insert,Delete,Update Call Procedure, Triggering etc etc). Both are accessing same Schema.

Thanks

Comment: From VB6 to .NET 4.5 ? Good luck !

Comment: The only thing I can think of is difficulty mixing and matching ADO and ADO .NET transactions with each other.

Answer (score 2):

OleDb is more generic. If you ever move to a different database type in the future there's a good chance it'll have an Ole driver and you won't have to change as much code.

On the other hand, the Sql Server native driver is supposed to be faster as you said and it has nicer parameter support (parameters can use names and don't have to be in order).

There were some limitations in ado library some of the following were known limitations

1. Hierarchical recordsets aren’t supported.

2.Server-side cursors (other than FO-RO cursors) are supported only for Microsoft SQL Server databases.

3.Multiple, semicolon-delimited SQL statements are supported in Recordset.Open methods, but not in the Execute method of the Connection and Command objects.

4.Parameterized stored procedures are not supported with Oracle databases

5.Asynchronous execution is allowed for the Open method of Connection and Recordset objects, but not for the Execute method of the Connection and Command objects.

6.The UpdateBatch method of the Recorset object requires that the SQL source statement includes the key fields of all involved tables and doesn’t work with old-syntax JOIN statements, with nested SELECT statements, and with derivate tables.
7. The SELECT statement used to open server-side keyset and dynamic cursors must include at least one non-nullable key column.

8.The Move method doesn’t work and raises an exception with serverside dynamic cursors.

9.The Index, Seek, MarshalOption, StayInSync members of the Recordset class aren’t implemented and are marked as obsolete.

10.The PageSize, Clone, and Find members of the Recordset class aren’t implemented for keysets and other server-side cursors.

11.The CommandStream, Dialect, NamedParameters, and Prepared members of the Command class aren’t implemented and are marked as obsolete.

12.The ReadText, WriteText, and SkipLines methods of the Stream class aren’t implemented and are marked as obsolete.

13.A few dynamic properties of the Connection or Recordset objects aren’t supported.

14.The ADODB.Record class isn’t supported.

Some of the feautres are partially or not supported

hope it helps